# What's wrong here and how can I calculate autocorrelation?

Tags: matlab

```
f1 = 1 ;    
N = 1024 ;    
fs = 200 ;    
ts = 1/fs ;    
t = -(N/(2*fs)):ts:(N/(2*fs)) ;    
theta=rand(0:2*pi);    

X = sin(2*pi*f1*t+theta) ;

plot(t,x)    
grid

Error using  + 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
```

And how can i calculate the autocorrelation of x function Rxx(n) ?

Comment: why you are not going for this http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/autocorr.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace the `theta` line by

   ```
   theta = 2*pi*rand; %// generates a random number between 0 and 2*pi
   ```

   and the `plot` line by

   ```
   plot(t, X); %// capital "X", as you have defined previously
   ```
2. For the autocorrelation, you can use [`conv`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/conv.html) (correlation for real signals is equivalent to convolution with a time-reversal):

   ```
   c = conv(X,fliplr(X));
   plot(-(N/fs):ts:(N/fs), c)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

To add to what Luis Mendo has answered, the reason for the error message is that:

```
>> size(t)
ans =

      1   1025

>> size(theta)
ans =

   0   1   2   3   4   5   6
```

So you are trying to add two things which are not the same dimension in `X = sin(2*pi*f1*t+theta)`, hence the error message.

Use Luis's suggestions to fix your code.